# Enforcing correct parameter types in derived virtual function

Tags: c++, oop

I'm finding it difficult to describe this problem very concisely, so I've attached the code for a demonstration program.

The general idea is that we want a set of Derived classes that are forced to implement some abstract Foo() function from a Base class. Each of the derived Foo() calls must accept a different parameter as input, but all of the parameters should also be derived from a BaseInput class.

We see two possible solutions so far, neither we're very happy with:

1. Remove the Foo() function from the base class and reimplement it with the correct input types in each Derived class. This, however, removes the enforcement that it be implemented in the same manner in each derived class.
2. Do some kind of dynamic cast inside the receiving function to verify that the type received is correct. However, this does not prevent the programmer from making an error and passing the incorrect input data type. We would like the type to be passed to the Foo() function to be compile-time correct.

Is there some sort of pattern that could enforce this kind of behaviour? Is this whole idea breaking some sort of fundamental idea underlying OOP? We'd really like to hear your input on possible solutions outside of what we've come up with.

Thanks so much!

```
#include <iostream>

// these inputs will be sent to our Foo function below
class BaseInput {};
class Derived1Input : public BaseInput { public: int   d1Custom; };
class Derived2Input : public BaseInput { public: float d2Custom; };

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo(BaseInput& i) = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    // we don't know what type the input is -- do we have to try to cast to what we want
    // and see if it works?
    virtual void Foo(BaseInput& i) { std::cout << "I don't want to cast this..." << std::endl; }

    // prefer something like this, but then it's not overriding the Base implementation
    //virtual void Foo(Derived1Input& i) { std::cout << "Derived1 did something with Derived1Input..." << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    // we don't know what type the input is -- do we have to try to cast to what we want
    // and see if it works?
    virtual void Foo(BaseInput& i) { std::cout << "I don't want to cast this..." << std::endl; }

    // prefer something like this, but then it's not overriding the Base implementation
    //virtual void Foo(Derived2Input& i) { std::cout << "Derived2 did something with Derived2Input..." << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 d1; Derived1Input d1i;
    Derived2 d2; Derived2Input d2i;

    // set up some dummy data
    d1i.d1Custom = 1;
    d2i.d2Custom = 1.f;

    d1.Foo(d2i);    // this compiles, but is a mistake! how can we avoid this?
                    // Derived1::Foo() should only accept Derived1Input, but then
                    // we can't declare Foo() in the Base class.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Polymorphism only works for references and pointers. What you've written will cause slicing in is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks -- we adjusted the calls to receive references instead.

Comment: @xtofl: Does C++ have covariant arguments for virtual functions, though? I thought it was only for the return type.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: C++ doesn't have it.  Actually, my comment contradicts my answer.  Downvote the comment :)

Comment: hmm, I'm catching a whiff of design smell.....

Comment: @xtofl: Hehe... actually, arguments should be *contravariant* -- the derived class's function should *accept* any base class of the argument type of the base class's function. *Now* I'm not sure if that's allowed in C++.

Comment: @David Heffernan So were we... that's why we asked the question. We're hoping to find the 'right' way of doing this without the 'smell'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `Derived` class *is-a* `Base` class, it should **never tighten the base contract preconditions**: if it has to behave like a `Base`, it should accept `BaseInput` allright.  This is known as the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Although you can do runtime checking of your argument, you can never achieve a fully type-safe way of doing this: your compiler may be able to match the `DerivedInput` when it sees a `Derived` object (static type), but it can not know what subtype is going to be behind a `Base` object...

The requirements

1. `DerivedX` should take a `DerivedXInput`
2. `DerivedX::Foo` should be interface-equal to `DerivedY::Foo`

contradict: either the `Foo` methods are implemented in terms of the `BaseInput`, and thus have identical interfaces in all derived classes, or the `DerivedXInput` types differ, and they *cannot* have the same interface.

That's, in my opinion, the problem.

This problem occured to me, too, when writing tightly coupled classes that are handled in a type-unaware framework:

```
class Fruit {};
class FruitTree { 
   virtual Fruit* pick() = 0;
};
class FruitEater {
   virtual void eat( Fruit* ) = 0;
};

class Banana : public Fruit {};
class BananaTree {
   virtual Banana* pick() { return new Banana; }
};
class BananaEater : public FruitEater {
   void eat( Fruit* f ){
      assert( dynamic_cast<Banana*>(f)!=0 );
      delete f;
   }
};
```

And a framework:

```
struct FruitPipeLine {
    FruitTree* tree;
    FruitEater* eater;
    void cycle(){
       eater->eat( tree->pick() );
    }
};
```

Now this proves a design that's too easily broken: there's no part in the design that aligns the trees with the eaters:

```
 FruitPipeLine pipe = { new BananaTree, new LemonEater }; // compiles fine
 pipe.cycle(); // crash, probably.
```

You may improve the cohesion of the design, and remove the need for virtual dispatching, by making it a template:

```
template<class F> class Tree {
   F* pick(); // no implementation
};
template<class F> class Eater {
   void eat( F* f ){ delete f; } // default implementation is possible
};
template<class F> PipeLine {
   Tree<F> tree;
   Eater<F> eater;
   void cycle(){ eater.eat( tree.pick() ); }
};
```

The implementations are really template specializations:

```
template<> class Tree<Banana> {
   Banana* pick(){ return new Banana; }
};


...
PipeLine<Banana> pipe; // can't be wrong
pipe.cycle(); // no typechecking needed.
```

Comment: We do not want the Derived1::Foo and Derived2::Foo to be implemented the same way. I tried to imply that by placing a different text output in each of them. The "actual" definition we want is *not* the one that accepts a BaseInput but the one that accepts the "correct" input for that class -- in those (commented-out) functions, the behaviour for each is different.

Comment: Although hammar was the first to suggest this sort of templated approach, your answer is the most complete. Thank you so much for your time! We think the templates should really clarify the problem and reduce the possibility of programmer error.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use a variation of the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
class Base {
public:
    // Stuff that don't depend on the input type.
};

template <typename Input>
class Middle : public Base {
public:
    virtual void Foo(Input &i) = 0; 
};    

class Derived1 : public Middle<Derived1Input> {
public:
    virtual void Foo(Derived1Input &i) { ... }
};

class Derived2 : public Middle<Derived2Input> {
public:
    virtual void Foo(Derived2Input &i) { ... }
};
```

Comment: Nice.  But why would you make `Foo` virtual?

Comment: @xtofl: In this case it was to force the derived classes to implement it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Don't both of them still derive from Base?

Comment: @Kerrek: Well, that's sort of the point. As [David pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181361/enforcing-correct-parameter-types-in-derived-virtual-function/7181728#7181728), the interfaces are different so they shouldn't be the same. This way, you can still share code between them, and you can extract the common interface into a base class of `Base<>`.

Comment: @Aardbeg: No, one derives from `Base<Derived1Input>`, the other from `Base<Derived2Input>`. Those are entirely different types. Think about `vector<int>` and `vector<double>`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Ahh, I see. I think, however, that this solution is very close to what we're looking for. We tried to be as clear as possible about the question, and I think hammar has got something workable. We need to do a bit of work to see if it's possible, but this seems the most "correct" to us.

Comment: It's entirely possible that there's a better design that meets your needs -- I just wanted to point out that this approach changes the design hierarchy (sort of from "vertical" to "horizontal", if you will). I have a feeling that this will in fact be nicer for your case, since you don't want the inheritance for its polymorphic power, but rather just to enforce an interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, just a shot from the hip!

If you don't mind the dynamic cast, how about this:

```
Class BaseInput;

class Base
{
public:
  void foo(BaseInput & x) { foo_dispatch(x); };
private:
  virtual void foo_dispatch(BaseInput &) = 0;
};

template <typename TInput = BaseInput> // default value to enforce nothing
class FooDistpatch : public Base
{
  virtual void foo_dispatch(BaseInput & x)
  {
    foo_impl(dynamic_cast<TInput &>(x));
  }
  virtual void foo_impl(TInput &) = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public FooDispatch<Der1Input>
{
  virtual void foo_impl(Der1Input & x) { /* your implementation here */ }
};
```

That way, you've built the dynamic type checking into the intermediate class, and your clients only ever derive from `FooDispatch<DerivedInput>`.

Comment: +1, even if I would *overload* in `FooDispatch` rather than create a function with a different name.

Comment: @David: I'm more than happy to improve this thing, but what if `TInput` happens to be `BaseInput`, would overloading work?

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about are covariant argument types, and that is quite an uncommon feature in a language, as it breaks your contract: You promised to accept a `base_input` object because you inherit from `base`, but you want the compiler to *reject* all but a small subset of `base_input`s...

It is much more common for programming languages to offer the opposite: *contra-variant* argument types, as the derived type will not only accept everything that it is bound to accept by the contract, but also other types.

At any rate, C++ does not offer contravariance in argument types either, only covariance in the return type.

Comment: So... does C++ have contravariant argument types in virtual functions?

Comment: @Kerrek: :) I was correcting parts of the question and I deleted that bit... No, C++ has covariant return types, but exact argument types. That is, you can return a derived type in the final overrider of a virtual function, but the arguments must be an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a lot of dark areas, so it's hard to say any specific thing is undoable, but going from the dark areas I do know, without a cast, this cannot be done.  The virtual function specified in the base class requires the argument type to remain the same in all the children.

I am sure a cast can be used in a non-painful way though, perhaps by giving the base class an Enum 'type' member that is uniquely set by the constructor of each possible child that might possibly inherit it.  Foo() can then check that 'type' and determine which type it is before doing anything, and throwing an assertion if it is surprised by something unexpected.  It isn't compile time, but it's the closest a compromise I can think of, while still having the benefits of requiring a Foo() be defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly restricted, but you can use/simulate coviarance in constructors parameters.