# C++: override or overload?

Tags: c++, overloading, overriding

I have two classes representing contexts for some methods.

```
class BaseContext {};
class DerivedContext : public BaseContext {};
```

I have a base class:

```
class MyBase {
protected:
  virtual void doSome(BaseContext* context);
};
```

And a derived class:

```
class MyDerived : public MyBase {
protected:
  virtual void doSome(DerivedContext* context) override; // Overriding
  virtual void doSome(DerivedContext* context); // Overloading?
};
```

Since `DerivedContext` derives from `BaseContext`, it might seems that I am overriding `doSome`. But it might also be an overloading...

1. Which one is correct? Am I overriding or overloading here?
2. Thus, if I type `(MyBase* my = new MyDerived())->doSome(new DerivedContext())`, what should I get?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181361/enforcing-correct-parameter-types-in-derived-virtual-function

Comment: Your derived type has two identical methods - `override` doesn't change the type - which isn't allowed. Was one of them supposed to take a `BaseContext` argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is neither overriding nor overloading. Since the parameter's type is different, `MyDerived::doSome` is just *hiding* `MyBase::doSome`.

> 1.1. Since `DerivedContext` derives from `BaseContext`, it might seems that I am overriding `doSome`.

No. Here're the preconditions of overriding listed in the standard. [$10.3/2 Virtual functions
[class.virtual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#2):

(emphasis mine)

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, **parameter-type-list** ([dcl.fct]), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it **overrides**[<sup>110</sup>](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#footnote-110) `Base::vf`.
>
> [110)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#footnote-110) A function with the same name but a different parameter list (Clause [over]) as a virtual function is not necessarily virtual and **does not override**.

In fact with [override specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) you'll get a [compile error](http://rextester.com/AZIOB20883) for this case. e.g.

```
error: 'doSome' marked 'override' but does not override any member functions
```

> 1.2. But it might also be an overloading...

You [can't overload](http://rextester.com/MFT62301) functions across scopes according to the rule of [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) (unless using [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) to introduce names into the same scope).

> 2. Thus, if I type `(MyBase* my = new MyDerived())->doSome(new DerivedContext())`, what should I get?

`MyBase::doSome()` will be invoked since you call it on a `MyBase*`. This is not overriding, so no dynamic dispatching happens here.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/RMZ12032)

<sup>Note the argument `DerivedContext*` will be implicitly converted to `BaseContext*` and then passed to the function. BTW `(MyBase* my = new MyDerived())->...` is not valid syntax.</sup>

Comment: I dont think its hidden. u can still call doSome(BaseContext*) as well.

Comment: @WikiWang You'll can't call it on `MyDerived`. See http://rextester.com/HMLR15127

Comment: @WikiWang you have to add `using MyBase::doSome;` to `MyDerived` to bring back the base overload.

Comment: @songyuanyao Well, the origin code marks those function protected, and you can call it within MyDerived::some_function using MyBase::doSome(...).

Comment: @WikiWang Yes, you just can't call it like `doSome(...)`, you have to call it like `MyBase::doSome(...)`, this is so-called name hiding.

Comment: @songyuanyao yeah you are right, i wasn't clear of it. Thank you~

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. So if I have just one more question. Please see my edited question (second point in the end). I am assuming that, after your clarification, the `doSome` in `MyDerived` is called as it matches the signature (provided I used the second signature in `MyDerived`)

Comment: @Andry Answer edited. Since it's not overriding, `MyBase::doSome()` will be invoked. No dynamic dispatching here.

Answer (score 1):

While only specifying the member function with another argument type, you are hiding the function from the base class.
With the `override` specifier you should get a compile error as there is no such function (with the exact same signature) in the base class.

**Overriding** is when *redefining* virtual a member function in a derived class with the *exact same arguments* (number *and* type). The `override` specifier is optional but encouraged as it helps identifying subtle bugs as in your case.

**Overloading** is when defining a function (not necessarily member of a class) with a different number or types of arguments.

Comment: "or the redefining a non-virtual member function in a derived class." It's still hiding, not overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Just put override after the function definition and see if it compiles. If it compiles, it is overriding the virtual method in the base class. If it does not, it would *hide* the base class method.